# Scraping data from this site using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I  am  noob to data scraping and learning the rope
i am going to scrape data values from this website, https://www.twhouse.co.uk/index.php?route=product/catalog, i am using scrapy shell to interogate and assemble my crawler .
When i initiate response, response.css('div.caption span.stat-1').get()
i got this
SKU: 8644'
i want to extract the value of the sku.
thank you all for your support

from scrapy shell i want to interrogate the url https://www.twhouse.co.uk/index.php?route=product/catalog
response.css('div.caption span.stat-1').get()
gave me this,

'SKU: 8644'
i want only the sku value from this, when i change is to response.css('div.caption span.stats-label').get()
i got this SKU:', when i inserted '::text' response.css('div.caption span.stats-label::text').get() i got this response  'SKU:' , not the sku value. how do i get the value

Answer (score 2):

The HTML looks like this:

```
...
...
<span class="stat-1">
    <span class="stats-label">SKU:</span>
    <span>8811</span>
</span>
...
...
```

So you want to get the second (last) `span` tag inside the outer `span` tag ("stat-1").

```py
scrapy shell https://www.twhouse.co.uk/index.php?route=product/catalog

>>> response.css('div.caption span.stat-1 span:last-child::text').get()
'8811'
```

If you want to get all the text you can use [getall()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=getall#scrapy.selector.Selector.getall) and you'll get them as a list.

```py
scrapy shell https://www.twhouse.co.uk/index.php?route=product/catalog

>>> response.css('div.caption span.stat-1 span:last-child::text').getall()
['8811', '8943', '8939', '8730', '8853', '8748', '8901', '8756', '8855', '8951', '8838', '8857', '8934', '8856', '8924', '9050', '8862', '8863', '8764', '9047', '9045', '9055', '8746', '8814', '8714', '8760', '8944', '8958', '8959', '8722', '8743', '8785', '8946', '8860', '8877', '8715', '9011', '8945', '9023', '8947', '9015', '8777', '8753', '8797', '8899', '8734', '8705', '9042', '8936', '8787', '8950', '8888', '8723', '9018', '9019', '8948', '8942', '8890', '8969', '8906', '8907', '8960', '9021', '8713', '9009', '9014', '9022', '8831', '8707', '8724', '9033', '9024', '9038', '8829', '9034', '9027', '9025', '9031', '9026', '9029', '9030', '9032', '9041', '9039', '9051', '9028', '8994', '8765', '8977', '8808', '8978', '8809', '8876', '9008', '8883', '8768', '8823', '8740', '8873', '9013']
```

Comment: thank you SuperUser, can you please point me books or video that i could learn more about grabbing data from  "last child"   or something like this

Comment: I don't know any books. Search for [CSS selectors cheat sheet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=css+selectors+cheat+sheet). I prefer to use [xpath selectors](https://devhints.io/xpath), read about them too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access second `span` child in `stat-1`

```
response.css('div.caption span.stat-1 span:nth-child(2)::text').get()
```

Comment: thank you Irem, am honored it worked like a charm